# Duplicate google form responses to another sheet as value automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

is there any script or formula that can help me do the data cleaning. For example in the sheet below, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mLZ8TYNpNHVN1Kc8QF80Ns3RX-EXdSz5s9WmHoIS8Pw/edit?usp=sharing, I have "Form responses 1" which capture the data entry from google form and "cleaning data" sheet. I tried to use Arrayformula and Importrange but i cannot edit the data in "Cleaning data" sheet. Currently, I just copy and paste manually to the other sheet.

What I wanna do

1. Respondent enter data in google form.
2. Data appear in "Form responses 1" sheet.
3. Updated data in "Form responses 1" automatically copied and paste in the "Cleaning data" sheet by row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, [please install OnSubmit trigger to the function `onSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you use this script, please submit your Google Form. By this, the script of `onSubmit` is run by firing the OnSubmit trigger.

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const srcSheet = range.getSheet();
  const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Cleaning Data");
  const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn());
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, {contentOnly: true});
}
```

#### Note:

- **In this script, please don't directly run this function with the script editor. Because this script uses the event object of OnSubmit trigger. When you directly run this script an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)